# Can we refer to a column from sysconstraints using name in sybase?

Tags: sybase, liquibase

since the option of accessing via 'name' attribute is possible via

> sysobjects

, is the same possible by

> sysconstraints/syscolumns??

because i have not given id attribute to table or column or any constraints.

Answer (score 1):

*sysobjects* does not contains any column name. I don't understand your first statement.
But if you have a **table name** and want to display *sysconstraints* table from table name and column name you can have a join like this :

```
SELECT constrid
FROM sysconstraints sc
  JOIN sysobjects o ON o.id = sc.tableid
  JOIN syscolumns c ON c.colid = sc.colid AND c.id = o.id
WHERE o.name = 'tablename'
AND c.name = 'columnname'
```

The *sysconstraints* has *colid* and *tableid* columns that match *syscolumns.colid* and *sysobjects.id*.